# Debug var on php inside js

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a script ([editablegrid](http://www.editablegrid.net/en)) that loads an php file (loaddata.php) inside a js file(JSON)(demo.js). When i make a js alert on php file:

```
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("message successfully sent")';
echo '</script>';
```

Script stopped and alert it's not show. If i remove this echo's script works fine. How can i make an alert to see a var (an $sql var)?

Thanks

Comment: According to your demo url, you are loading it like this : `this.editableGrid.loadJSON(url);` ? If yes, try to load it using different way since the data is supposed to be json

Comment: I can do with XML, but with loadXML, i can't do any echo on loaddata.php neither

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are echoing inside an already opened  `<script>`  tag.

Try removing `echo '<script language="javascript">';` and `echo '</script>'`.

Comment: No, it doesnt works. If i write only echo someting script stop and not show data. If i remove this echo data is showed well. And i need to write echo for debug a var. Thanks

Comment: Probably the console is throwing some info that will help us know what is going on. Press F12,  select the console and paste here what it is showing.

Comment: Here it's error SyntaxError: missing ) in parenthetical
 

(test{"metadata":[{"name":"post_title","label":"Cliente","datatyp. 

Test it's a echo

Comment: Looks like the JSON data is badly formatted. Probably the closing `)` is missing.

Comment: But this error it's only when i make an "echo ,,,,". I think that when encode JSON, it's encoded badly and shows this error. But i don't know how can i do it

Answer (score 0):

To debug I use the following to save data from php into javascript.
Flavor to your liking:

```
<?php
$aTmp[ 'data1' ] = 'coolstuff1!';
$aTmp[ 'data2' ] = 'coolstuff2!';
echo '<script>';
echo "var oData = [];";
echo 'var oData = ' . json_encode( $aTmp ) . ';';
echo 'console.log( oData );';
echo '</script>';
?>
```

Comment: If i paste this code, script stopped and message it's not show. I don't know why. If i put a simple echo "Hello", script don't run

Comment: Use browser's console to inspect data.
Right click open console and you'll see the data under logging section.
Check out firebug! https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/

Comment: I can't see on Firebug. Look http://www.gestoriabarcelona.com/gestion/demo/listado.php?tipo_de_empresa=Sociedades

Comment: Can anyone install editablegrid an test how to make a debug inside loaddata.php file?

Comment: I see a syntax error on firefox:
Right click,
Inspect Element,
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
Can you post the file you're running? I edit my original post to include php tags you may have been missing.

Comment: Here php loaddata.php http://pastie.org/10009139. At the end of file you can see $sql var that must be debugged. If i remove "echo "test"" all works fine, but if i want to echo something, the script stoped. Here js file that loads loaddata.php http://pastie.org/10009142. On line 77. Thanks

Comment: Looking at the original link with firebug shows an error: [setCellRenderer] Invalid column: action Appears to be pointing to: // render for the action column
 grid.setCellRenderer("action", new CellRenderer({ 
  render: function(cell, id) {                 
        cell.innerHTML+= "<i onclick=\"datagrid.deleteRow("+id+");\" class='fa fa-trash-o red' ></i>";
  }
 }));

Comment: But this error it's only when i make an "echo ,,,,". I think that when encode JSON, it's encoded badly and shows this error. But i don't know how can i do it

Comment: JSON it's incorrect when i make an echo on loaddata.php. Without echo, json format it's correct {.....}. But when i make an echo (p.e: echo "test") on php file, JSON code its test{.....}

Comment: Then move the echo outside of the json parse/output?

Comment: But i don't know how ;)